# how testing a controller which return json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

please help write test for controller.

page have ajax-button for display detail info about image:

```
$('#thumbsList .thumb').on('click', function(){
  var imageId = $(this).closest('article').attr('data-image-id'),
      form = $(this).closest('form');

  $.ajax({
    url: '/images/' + imageId,
    type: 'GET',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(image){     
      $('#detailImageMeta').html(constructMeta(image));
    }       
  });
});
```

route:

```
image GET    /images/:id(.:format)                        images#show
```

imageController:

```
  def show
    image_detail = Image.find(image_params[:image_id])

    if image_detail
      render json: {
        user_id: image_detail.user_id
      }, :status => 200 
    else
      render nothing: true, :status => 404 
    end
  end
```

spec/controllers/image_controller_spec.rb:

```
it 'response is success' do
  image = FactoryGirl.create(:image)      
  get :show, id: image.id, image_id: image.id
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

but when i run spec in console then get follow error message:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/phs $ rspec spec/controllers/images_controller_spec.rb
FFF
Failures:
  1) ImagesController GET #show response is success
     Failure/Error: get :show, id: image.id, image_id: image.id
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: image
```

please help testing controller

Comment: In your controller, you have this: `image_detail = Image.find(image_params[:image_id])`, should it be: `params[:image_id]? instead of `image_params[:image_id]`? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller's `show` action,

Change:

```
image_detail = Image.find(image_params[:image_id])
```

To:

```
image_detail = Image.find(params[:image_id])
```